# Is there another way to annotate Count/Sum in existing queryset?

Tags: django

Let me illustrate the problem with canonical models Book&Author:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()    
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the view:

```
class Report(ListView):
...
def get_queryset(self):
    ... # calculating of filters
    return Book.objects.filter(status='published', date= ... a bunch of filters)
```

So that we have a queryset with all necessary filters. It might be used in another functions, for example, to get the number of books:

```
    def books_number(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.count()
```

or cost of all these books:

```
    def summa(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

Now, I want to get number of books by each Author and their costs and I would be happy with something like this:

```
    def authors_info(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return Author.objects.annotate(books_number=Count( use qs somehow ... ),
                                       books_cost = Sum( use qs over field 'price' somehow ...)
                                      )
```

but I haven't yet found a way to do that.

Well, to get it working I used this:

```
    def authors_info(self):
        ... # calculating of THE SAME filters AGAIN

        q_ = Q(status='published', date= ... a bunch of filters)
        count_ = Count('book', filter=q_)
        sum_ = Sum('book__price', filter=q_)
        return Author.objects.annotate(books_number=count_,
                                       books_cost=sum_)
```

but it definitely contradicts with DRY principle.

Is still there more tidy way to get queryset in one function and to annotate it in another function?

Comment: You can share the models?

Comment: I've added models, they are like from Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/